# vuejs add/remove class by referencing bool in an array

Tags: vue.js

I am adding/removing a class based on boolean value. Works as just a bool but not if bool in array
This line works, the opaque class gets added/removed:

```
<img v-bind:class="{opaque: slide1}" src="img/forest-field.jpg" />
```

This line does not work, the opaque class does not get added/removed:

```
<img v-bind:class="{opaque: slideBools[0]}" src="img/forest-field.jpg" />
```

the code in instance data:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#myCarousel',
  data: {
    slideBools: [true, false, false, false],
    slide1: true,
    slide2: false,
    slide3: false,
    slide4: false,
    },
  },
});
```

I am updating the bool value in an instance method like this:

```
  methods: {
    startSlides: function () {
      var vm = this;
      setInterval(() => {
        vm.slideBools[vm.curImage] = true;
      }, 4000);
    },
  }
```

Update question: I am wondering if how I reference the array value from html is where the problem lies

Comment: where you are updating array value?

Answer (score 1):

While updating the array value use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) or its alias [`this.$set` method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) to reflect in the DOM since its a nested property updating directly won't reflect in all cases.

```
this.$set(this.slideBools, 0, true)
```

Refer [Vue documentation about reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) for more information.

---

**UPDATE :** In your case, the code would be like as follows:

```
  methods: {
    startSlides: function () {
      var vm = this;
      setInterval(() => {
        v.$set(vm.slideBools, vm.curImage, true);
      }, 4000);
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your data prop to:

```js
data() {
    return {
        slideBools: [true, false, false, false],
        slide1: true,
        slide2: false,
        slide3: false,
        slide4: false,
    };
  },
```